# Using Advance Installer,is it possible to add EULA, when bootstrapper-UI level is in Basic UI and progress (or) Silent Install(no UI)

Tags: advanced-installer

I need to add EULA dialog, before prequisites installation starts, after i agree the EULA only, prequisites and my application should start installing,make sure that BootstrapperUI(i.e., UI level should be in Basic UI and progress (or)Silent install(no UI)) but no in full UI,please guide me in a proper way, i am very new to advance installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic UI means only a progress bar is shown. So to show an EULA dialog the bootstrapper needs full UI.

To hide the prerequisites you can simply change them to [feature-based](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/prerequisites.html) instead of global. This way you can show LicenseAgreementDlg before the prerequisites are installed. After that, you can simply delete all dialogs except LicenseAgreementDlg and ProgressDlg.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,As per your last post,i changed my prerequisites to Feature-based,and changed bootstrapper to full UI, after i start running the application, EULA doesn't occur,Just simple progress bar is shown and pre-requisites installation gets completed, I am new to advance installer, if you have any setup file pls attach it, it will be easy for me to understand..

Comment: It looks like the bootstrapper doesn't show the EULA if there are no global prerequisites. I updated my answer.